# App Engine prevent posting duplicates to datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I'm learning python and GAE. I've been able to build a basic app, but I'm running into accidental duplicate entries. I'm not sure, but I think that I might be able to deal with this by using a key name, but I'm still learning and have been confused by the examples that I found explaining key names.

What I'd like to do is use a string as an "entry id" so that before an entry is posted, the script makes sure that there's not already an entry with the same entry "idstring". I've built some messy code that builds a list and checks the entry against the list, but I suspect that there is a more efficient way to do this?

Here's my code:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Options(db.Model):
  idstring = db.StringProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')

    options = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                            "FROM Options "
                            "LIMIT 10")

    for entry in options:
        self.response.out.write('%s ' % entry.idstring)
        self.response.out.write('Content: %s <br>' % entry.content)
    self.response.out.write("""
          <form action="/sign" method="post">
                <div class="field-field">
                <select name="idstring" id="id_string">
                  <option value="unique1">ID1</option>
                  <option value="unique2">ID2</option>
                  <option value="unique3">ID3</option>
                </select>
            <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>""")


class Optionbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def post(self):
      idlist = Options.all()
      idlist2 = []
      for i in idlist:
        idlist2.append(i.idstring)
      idstring = self.request.get('idstring')
      if idstring not in idlist2:
        entry = Options()
        entry.content = self.request.get('content')
        entry.idstring = self.request.get('idstring')
        entry.put()
      self.redirect('/')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainPage),
  ('/sign', Optionbook)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In retrospect the solution was very simple. When adding entries to the datastore, the datastore can either use an entity key_id or key_name as a key. If you'd like to use a key name, simply add key_name = yourkeystring to your put code:

```
  import webapp2
  from google.appengine.ext import db

  class Options(db.Model):
    idstring = db.StringProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

  class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      self.response.out.write('<html><body>')

      options = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                              "FROM Options "
                              "LIMIT 10")

      for entry in options:
          self.response.out.write('Content: %s <br>' % entry.content)
      self.response.out.write("""
            <form action="/sign" method="post">
                  <div class="field-field">
                  <select name="yourkeystring" id="yourkeystring">
                    <option value="ID1">ID1</option>
                    <option value="ID2">ID2</option>
                    <option value="ID3">ID3</option>
                  </select>
              <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
              <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>""")


  class Optionbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
          n = Options(
            content = self.request.get('content'),
            key_name = self.request.get('yourkeystring'))
          n.put()
          self.redirect('/')


  app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Optionbook)
  ], debug=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? I get AttributeError: type object 'xxx' has no attribute 'key_name'